# Quickest way to get the min and max from a list of lists of lists in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have this list:

```py
x_train = [
    [[0, 2, 5], [95, -5, 100]], 
    [[0, 97, 4], [12, 15, 18]]
]
```

I'm trying to figure out the quickest way to get the minimum and maximum value of each position in the list of three numbers across the whole array. My actual data is in the shape of `5000000, 20, 3` so what I'm currently doing is taking a pretty long time to complete.

Here's my solution which takes about 16 seconds:

```py
x_train = np.random.rand(1000000, 20, 3)
v_ego = min([inner[0] for outer in x_train for inner in outer])
v_lead = min([inner[1] for outer in x_train for inner in outer])
x_lead = min([inner[2] for outer in x_train for inner in outer])
```

Is there a simpler and quicker way that doesn't require iterating through the entire array every time I want to find the next min or max?

Comment: min and max can take iterables, you don't need to materialise the whole list and pass it in.

Comment: I haven't used iterables, so I'm not sure the correct way to approach them for this case. Would I use lambda for this?

Comment: Just remove the square brackets, pass a generator expression rather than the result of a list comprehension.

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want to get the maximum and minimum value across each of the rows?

Comment: I'm not sure about this since I didn't do it before but if I want to implement this and a fast execution is needed I ll personally use numpy because it's interfacing a C/C++ Code.

Comment: Thanks @basilisk. You just made me add numpy to my Google search which led me to the solution!

Comment: OK, looking at your example it looks like a question of re-shaping your array. If I understand correctly, what you need is to `x_train.reshape(3, 20000000)[0].max()` for the first value (or `.min()` respectively, 1 for the 2-nd, etc.

Comment: Oh my bad, I misunderstood your question. I wanted to get the min and max of each of the positions in the rows across the whole array, for normalization. I found a good solution with numpy, thanks though!

Comment: @ShaneSmiskol glad I could help. remmember that when you import numpy and use its functions, you are actually using C or C++ Code behind the scene and python is just an Interface for it. so whenever you need fast Execution just use some Library in Python which was implemented in C. Python Code can be optimised using generators etc.. but it will never reach the speed execution of C/C++ Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have done a little more research before asking, but I just discovered `np.take` and `np.amax`.

For my example, here's what I did:

```
index = 0
np.amin(np.take(x_train, indices=index, axis=2))
```

From what took 16 seconds now takes .34!

Comment: but with this approach you have to set `index = ...` for each column `0, 1, 2`. Does not look automated

Comment: I only have three types of data that I need it for, so it's perfect for me. Of course you could set up a for loop with the length of how many min/maxs you want

Comment: Try `np.amax(xtrain, axis=(0,1))`

Comment: Your `np.random.rand(1000000, 20, 3)` makes a 3d numpy array.  It is not a list of lists of lists.  It can be treated as such, though it would be better to change it with `x_train.to_list()`.  But since it is already an array it's best to use `numpy` functions and methods, not list ones.

Comment: Just to clarify @hpaulj's suggestion: `v_ego,v_lead,x_lead = np.min(x_train,axis=(0,1))` does all in one go.

Comment: @hpaulj you're right, I'm new to working with arrays and all, so I'm still learning!

Answer (score 0):

After flattening/reshaping the input array you'll be able to get minimum and maximum for **all** columns in one pass:

```
x_train = np.array([[[0, 2, 5], [95, -5, 100]], [[0, 97, 4], [12, 15, 18]]])
x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0] * x_train.shape[1], 3))

all_mins = np.min(x_train, axis=0)
all_maxs = np.max(x_train, axis=0)
print(all_mins)   # [ 0 -5  4]
print(all_maxs)   # [ 95  97 100]
```